# JavaScript regex back references returning an array of matches from single capture group (multiple groups)

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, regex-group, capturing-group

I'm fairly sure after spending the night trying to find an answer that this isn't possible, and I've developed a work around - but, if someone knows of a better method, I would love to hear it...

I've gone through a lot of iterations on the code, and the following is just a line of thought really. At some point I was using the global flag, I believe, in order for match() to work, and I can't remember if it was necessary now or not.

```
var str = "@abc@def@ghi&jkl";
var regex = /^(?:@([a-z]+))?(?:&([a-z]+))?$/;
```

The idea here, in this simplified code, is the optional group 1, of which there is an unspecified amount, will match @abc, @def and @ghi. It will only capture the alpha characters of which there will be one or more. Group 2 is the same, except matches on & symbol. It should also be anchored to the start and end of the string.

I want to be able to back reference all matches of both groups, ie:

```
result = str.match(regex);
alert(result[1]); //abc,def,ghi
alert(result[1][0]); //abc
alert(result[1][1]); //def
alert(result[1][2]); //ghi
alert(result[2]); //jkl
```

My mate says this works fine for him in .net, unfortunately I simply can't get it to work - only the last matched of any group is returned in the back reference, as can be seen in the following:

(additionally, making either group optional makes a mess, as does setting global flag)

```
var str = "@abc@def@ghi&jkl";
var regex = /(?:@([a-z]+))(?:&([a-z]+))/;

var result = str.match(regex);

alert(result[1]); //ghi
alert(result[1][0]); //g
alert(result[2]); //jkl
```

---

The following is the solution I arrived at, capturing the whole portion in question, and creating the array myself:

```
var str = "@abc@def@ghi&jkl";
var regex = /^([@a-z]+)?(?:&([a-z]+))?$/;

var result = regex.exec(str);

alert(result[1]); //@abc@def@ghi
alert(result[2]); //jkl

var result1 = result[1].toString();
result[1] = result1.split('@')

alert(result[1][1]); //abc
alert(result[1][2]); //def
alert(result[1][3]); //ghi
alert(result[2]); //jkl
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's simply not how `.match()` works in JavaScript. The returned array is an array of simple strings. There's no "nesting" of capture groups; you just count the `(` symbols from left to right.

The first string (at index `[0]`) is always the overall matched string. Then come the capture groups, one string (or `null`) per array element.

You can, as you've done, rearrange the result array to your heart's content. It's just an array.

*edit* — oh, and the reason your `result[1][0]` was "g" is that array indexing notation applied to a string gets you the individual characters of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought there may have been a more elegant solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1412662/1455709 was the closest answer I was able to find, however had no success when complicating the expression and shoe horn it into what I was after...